# Receive JSON Data and just send it back

Tags: aws-lambda

Im using phyton to try to create a lambda function that receives a json body and does no transformation and returns it the same.

I am havinga hard time trying to do that, I can do transformations in the lambda when i do not need to send data to the lambda function but when trying I always get errors.

I tried to send data with :

```
json.dumps or json.loads ["body"] but it always gives me keyerror.
```

This is was one code that i tried:

```
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):

data = json.dumps(event ['body'])

return data
```

Aswell as this one:

```
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):

data = json.dumps(event ['body'])

return data
```

Both give me errorType : "KeyError" when sending the jSON below

```
{"email": "test@gmail.com",
    "epCode" : "PMP",
    "EAN": "7891268118095",
    "transactionType" : "SALE"}
```

Comment: OK, so where are you stuck? Are you receiving errors? Have you even attempted to write any code yet? Have you even picked a programming language you want to use yet?

Comment: Yes yes! I am using phyton language, and when not receiving a json body or using like a get method i can write the function but when trying to receive a JSON i try to only return the body itself and always get keyerror "body" using the json.loads or dumps["body]

Comment: Edit your question to include all those details. As it is, people are voting to close your question because it doesn't include any of those details.

Comment: You still haven't given us relevant code snippet.  Show us the *exact* code, not some pseudocode summary

Comment: I dont have much code I am just testing new things, But regardless I will edit

Answer (score 0):

you didnt mention 'body' as key in your input , modify your input to this format,

```
{
  "body": {
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "epCode": "PMP",
    "EAN": "7891268118095",
    "transactionType": "SALE"
  }
}
```